# Ruby: How to store a dynamically generated list at the class level such that the list is only calculated once and ONLY IF the class is called upon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, class-variables

I have an ActiveRecord validation for some records that by default silently prevents my rails application from saving multiple versions of records with an identical string value like so:

```
class Boat < ActiveRecord::Base# not actual class name, but I like boating
   validates :boatname, :uniqueness => true
end
```

I would like to add a `before_validation` callback to my model like so...

```
require 'highline/import' #simplifies command prompt response code
class Boat < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :boatname

  before_validation do |r|
    pre_existing = Boat.find_by_boatname(r.boatname)
    if pre_existing
      puts "whoa! found a boat that already exists with the name '#{r.boatname}':"
      ap pre_existing #pretty prints the column names and values
      resp = ask("press 'o' to overwrite, 'm' to modify the new boat name so it gets added")
      if resp == "o"
        #..code handling responses
      end
   end
```

But this is computationally expensive to an absurd degree. I was thinking about handling it like this, which brings us to my actual question:

```
require 'highline/import' #simplifies command prompt response code
class Boat < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :boatname
  @@existing_boats ||= all.map(&:boatname)

  before_validation do |r|
    if @@existing_boats.include?(r.boatname)
      puts "whoa! found a boat that already exists with the name '#{r.boatname}':"
      ap pre_existing #pretty prints the column names and values
      resp = ask("press 'o' to overwrite, 'm' to modify the new boat name so it gets added")
      if resp == "o"
        #..code handling responses
      end
   end
```

Is this the best way to handle something like this? Does it meet my criteria of only being loaded once per ruby/rails instance and only if the class is called upon? I was thinking maybe I'd have to put the `all.map(&:boatname)` component into a lambda or proc to prevent it from getting loading everytime rails is initialized but I'm not sure if that's necessary.

Accepting general criticism on my design approach as well, but that's not the purpose of the question.

Comment: Your second version is probably more expensive, not less (assuming that you have an index on boatname)

Comment: You're doing it wrong. The thing that tries to create `Boat`s should be doing the "overwrite/modify". You should also have a unique index on `boatname` in your database, that index should make the existence validation very fast.

Comment: Thanks @FrederickCheung, that comment alone was worth the cost of asking the question

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are trying to implement here

```
@@existing_boats ||= all.map(&:boatname)
```

is known as caching.
Basically, caching forces you to update the cached data as soon as it becomes out of date. Let 5 boats be saved inside of the database, what should be returned when users save other 10 boats? Saving the cache inside of a model forces you to use some outer timer solutions or additional model callbacks to update the cached value. This can be solved a way easier, take a look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011120/is-it-possible-to-cache-custom-sql-queries-in-rails) and [this tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores).

I'm also not sure about the time it takes to realize there is a duplicate value in a relational database. Do you have an index on boatname field? That query should not take long.

More on that, I'm not sure what's going on here:

```
resp = ask("press 'o' to overwrite, 'm' to modify the new boat name so it gets added")
```

MVC pattern implicates impossibility of asking for user input right inside the model layer, so you simply can not do this kind of things in rails.

Comment: its not a rails thing, I'm just using rails for ActiveRecord. I occasionally use the front end for utility purposes but for all intensive purposes there is none.